# Use a parameter value in a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, parameter-passing

I'm having issues getting a 'touchmove' event to fire using a parameter value in the callback function.  I have success if I pass an "alert" but not a function.  Basic concept in the example is the text box goes up by "1" (obj.number) on the 'touchmove' when it's scrolled within the selected div (ID="myDIV").

Here is an example:

```js
function myFunction(num) {
  document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = x += num;
}

function Scroller(area, obj) {
  $divarea = document.getElementById(area);
  $divarea.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    obj.alertMe(obj.number); // THIS WORKS
  });

  $divarea.addEventListener("touchmove", function() {
    obj.scrollMe(obj.number) // THIS DOES NOT WORK AND WHAT I NEED TO RUN, "obj.number" SHOULD BE 1
  });

  var x = 0;
}

$scroll = new Scroller("myDIV", {
  number: 1,
  alertMe: function(numberValue) {
    alert(numberValue)
  },
  scrollMe: function(numberValue) {
    myFunction(numberValue)
  }
})
```

The body is just basic HTML:

```
<div id="myDIV" >
    <!-- a bunch of text goes here so that it scrolls -->
</div>

<div id="divText" ></div>
```

Would greatly appreciate the overflow community in helping me spot my bug as I have put too much time already into what I know (hope) is going to be a simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Working fine...`x` is not defined..

Comment: Slightly better demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fawv25xe/

Comment: `x` is a local variable mate! Isn't accessible out of the function!

Comment: And remove `alert`(Do not use it for debugging), it will break the flow from `touchstart` to `touchmove`

Comment: Rayon Dabre, you're correct in that "x" was written as a local variable.  The function is now working as needed.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize x as a global variable and that will solve your issue

```
function Scroller(area, obj) {
  $divarea = document.getElementById(area);
  $divarea.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    obj.alertMe(obj.number); // THIS WORKS
  });

  $divarea.addEventListener("touchmove", function() {
    obj.scrollMe(obj.number) // THIS DOES NOT WORK AND WHAT I NEED TO RUN, "obj.number" SHOULD BE 1
  });

  x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @S Vinesh, "x" being a local variable was causing the issue.